# How to find Unix timestamp of a given calendar date and time in a specific time zone in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, time, timezone

With APIs like [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts), I can obtain the date and time of any Unix timestamp in any time zone. How can I do the reverse?

I'd like to be able to convert any particular triplet of `<calendar-date>` (YYYY-MM-DD), `<local-time>` (HH:MM:SS), and `<time-zone>` (IANA timezone) (which *do not necessarily* correspond with fixed timezone *offsets*) to a Unix timestamp. I am not looking to just convert the current timestamp (which is trivial) or looking for solutions that presuppose I have a Javascript Date object; what we have is only the calendar date, local time, and time zone.

Solutions such as adding time zone offsets do not work reliably (eg in cases of DST). I had hoped Intl allowed for easy calculation of this problem.

Comment: `new Date('1983-04-23T12:34:56+06:00').getTime()`…?! If you can create a `Date` object, then `getTime` is all you need. What does your input look like and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I cannot create a Date object because I am not starting off with a specific Unix timestamp; I am trying to *obtain* the timestamp. Since I do not have the timestamp, I cannot create the Date.

I cannot construct the timestamp string that way, since given an IANA time zone, I do not a priori know the timezone offset at any date, because of things like DST.

Comment: The `Date` constructor takes all sorts of inputs to construct a `Date` from, e.g. an ISO string as shown above, or individual values for year etc. Again, what exactly does your input look like? Once you have a `Date` object, obtaining the UNIX timestamp from it is a single function call. Is your actual question how to parse a specific input into a `Date` object?

Comment: If the task can be accomplished by Date, I would be happy. As far as the documentation I have gone through, I have not yet found ways to do so. The input is as stated in the question; a calendar date of YYYY-MM-DD, a local time HH:MM:SS, and an IANA timezone.

Comment: OK. I don't believe the standard JS `Date` API supports a named timezone to instantiate a `Date` object at all. You're pretty much required to resort to 3rd party libraries for that.

Comment: Alas that was my fear...

Comment: Unfortunately, `Intl` doesn't support this use case.  [Luxon does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77402463/634824), as do other libraries.  Eventually it will be built-in via TC39's [Temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/).  See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint The proposed standard Temporal API! I would be inclined to consider the revelation of your link to be a satisfactory answer to the posed question.

Comment: It's too early yet, as Temporal is still a stage 3 proposal.  Once it reaches stage 4, I'll consider using it in StackOverflow answers.  Thanks. (See https://tc39.es/process-document/)

Answer (score 1):

Does the Luxon version work for you?

```js
// const { DateTime } = require('luxon');

// Define your input values
const calendarDate = '2023-04-15';
const localTime = '12:30:00';
const timeZone = 'America/New_York'; // Example timezone, replace with your desired IANA timezone

// Combine calendar date and local time
const dateTimeString = `${calendarDate}T${localTime}`;

// Create a Luxon DateTime object in the specified timezone
const luxonObj = luxon.DateTime.fromISO(dateTimeString, { zone: timeZone }); // remove luxon. if you have required DateTime
console.log(luxonObj)
// Get the Unix timestamp
const unixTimestamp = luxonObj.toSeconds();

console.log(unixTimestamp);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/3.4.3/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

It was not trivial

```js
/**
 * Converts a calendar date and local time to a Unix timestamp.
 *
 * @param {string} calendarDate - The calendar date in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'.
 * @param {string} localTime - The local time in the format 'HH:mm:ss'.
 * @param {string} timeZone - The IANA time zone identifier.
 * @returns {number} The Unix timestamp in seconds.
 */
const convertToUnixTimestamp = (calendarDate, localTime, timeZone) => {
  const [hourStr, minuteStr, secondStr] = localTime.split(':');
  let hour = parseInt(hourStr, 10);
  const minute = parseInt(minuteStr, 10);
  const second = parseInt(secondStr, 10);

  const dateTimeString = `${calendarDate}T00:00:00`;

  // Set the locale to 'en-US' for consistent formatting
  const dtf = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit',
    timeZoneName: 'short',
    timeZone
  });

  // Format the date portion of the datetime string
  const formattedDate = dtf.format(new Date(dateTimeString));

  // Determine if it's in the afternoon based on the hour
  const isAfternoon = hour >= 12;

  // Replace "AM" or "PM" without appending when needed
  const formattedDateTime = formattedDate.replace(
    /(AM|PM)/,
    isAfternoon ? 'PM' : 'AM'
  );

  // Subtract 12 from the hour if it's in the afternoon (PM)
  if (isAfternoon) {
    hour -= 12;
  }

  // Combine the formatted date with the provided local time
  const formattedDateTimeWithTime = formattedDateTime.replace(
    /\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/,
    `${hour.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${minuteStr}:${secondStr}`
  );
  
  // Create a Date object with the formatted datetime string
  const date = new Date(formattedDateTimeWithTime);
  console.log(formattedDateTimeWithTime, "->", date);

  // Get the Unix timestamp in seconds
  const unixTimestamp = Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000);
  return unixTimestamp;
};

// Example usages:
const calendarDate = '2023-04-15';

let timeZone = 'America/New_York'; 
let localTime = '00:30:00'; // Example with '00'
let unixTimestamp = convertToUnixTimestamp(calendarDate, localTime, timeZone);
console.log(unixTimestamp);

localTime = '15:30:00'; // Example with military time
unixTimestamp = convertToUnixTimestamp(calendarDate, localTime, timeZone);
console.log(unixTimestamp);

timeZone = 'Europe/Amsterdam'; // another IANA timezone
localTime = '15:30:00';
unixTimestamp = convertToUnixTimestamp(calendarDate, localTime, timeZone);
console.log(unixTimestamp);
```

Comment: Thanks for putting in the effort to try to actually answer the question! Unfortunately, this answer suffers from 1) reparsing the date string; this format does not work in all Date implementations eg in Hermes (React Native); probably can be remedied by further munging to make the format fit ISO8601, but more importantly, 2) I don't see how this can handle DST correctly across edge cases, IIUC this assumes that consecutive days have the same offset, which is *just* almost always correct.